# Using default values to infill dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes with a number of the same column headers in each.

I'm looking to merge both dataframes but only use data from dataframe B if there is no data is dataframe A available, i.e. Dataframe B is default values which should be used if there is no data is dataframe A.

Dataframe A

```
             A  B  C
01/01/2020   78 45 78
02/01/2020   41 36 51
03/01/2020   81 43 51
04/01/2020   84 NaN NaN
05/01/2020   NaN NaN NaN
.
.
.
.
31/01/2022 NaN NaN NaN
```

Dataframe B;

```
            A  B   C
01/01/2020  40 30 60
02/01/2020  40 30 60
03/01/2020  40 30 60
04/01/2020  40 30 60
.
.
.
.
31/01/2025 40 30 60
```

Example 04/01/2020 would read;

```
04/01/2020 84 30 60
```

Any form of join/merge I do seems to overwrite values incorrectly.
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `df1`

```
               A     B     C
date                        
01/01/2020  78.0  45.0  78.0
02/01/2020  41.0  36.0  51.0
03/01/2020  81.0  43.0  51.0
04/01/2020  84.0   NaN   NaN
05/01/2020   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

and `df2`

```
             A   B   C
date                  
01/01/2020  40  30  60
02/01/2020  40  30  60
03/01/2020  40  30  60
04/01/2020  40  30  60
05/01/2020  40  30  60
```

Both having `date` as index

```
df3 = df1.fillna(df2)

               A     B     C
date                        
01/01/2020  78.0  45.0  78.0
02/01/2020  41.0  36.0  51.0
03/01/2020  81.0  43.0  51.0
04/01/2020  84.0  30.0  60.0
05/01/2020  40.0  30.0  60.0
```